# Only apply the property till the text, not whole the line

Tags: css

Here is my the dummy test.

Here is the HTML stuff:

```
<h1> Header </h1>
```

Here is the CSS stuff:

```
body {
 background: pink;
}

h1 {
 background-color: #454545;
}
```

The webpage is rendered something like this:

[image]

As you can se in this image, I applied the property to the `<h1>`, but the whole line has its effect.

What I want is, the gray background till the word "Header", not more than that *(Background color is just an example. This is not **only** the case.).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
h1{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to post the same. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
h1 {
background-color: #454545;
display: inline-block;
}
```

**edit**:

late... @Scrimothy already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span inside your heading tags.  Then you can use `h1 span{...}` as your css selector rather than setting all your headers or adding classes just to handle this.

I have a site where I want headers to act normally (and stretch across the width) but also need to have backgrounds just behind the text.

```css
body{
    background: pink;
}

h1{
    background-color: #454545;
}

h1 span{
    background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<h1>Normal heading with a background</h1>
<p>I'm some content</p>
<h1 style="background-color: transparent"><span>Heading with my content in a &lt;span&gt;</span></h1>
<p>I'm some more content</p>
```